# An array battle with odd secret powers

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

Here is a relatively simple two dimensional array challenge.

Imagine a battlefield of 625 foot soldiers. You command the ***odd*** troops, but unfortunately the strength of the ***even*** troops overwhelms you. Thankfully, your soldiers have a secret power: If the power of each odd troop and the fellow odd allies surrounding them is divisible by a secret power number, they unleash their *ultimate attack* and win! You must honor each victorious soldier.

**Rules**

Given a 25 x 25 integer array where each element contains the product of its x and y position plus 1, return the coordinates of every "victorious" odd element that meets the following criteria:

The sum of the element's value and its adjacent odd elements (up, down, left, and right) is divisible by the input (secret power number). It must have elements adjacent to it on all four sides and not be on an edge.

Submissions can be either a function or full program that requires a single input. The output can be in any order.

Our 25 x 25 array, the battlefield, looks like this:

```
1, 1, 1, 1,...
1, 2, 3, 4,...
1, 3, 5, 7,...
1, 4, 7, 10,...
etc.
```

**Example**

Here is a 3 x 3 example:

```
43, 57, 71
46, 61, 76
49, 65, 81
```

To determine if an element (61, in the center) wins, we sum the values of it and the adjacent odd elements.

```
61 + 57 + 65 = 183
```

If the total is divisible by the input, the element's x and y position is printed. If our input is 3, because 183 is divisible by 3, "1, 1" is printed.

**Output**

If the input (secret power number) is 37, the elements returned (victorious soldiers to be commended) must be:

```
2, 18
3, 12
4, 9
5, 22
6, 6
8, 23
9, 4
10, 11
11, 10
12, 3
18, 2
22, 5
23, 8
```

If the input is 191, the elements returned must be:

```
10, 19
19, 10
```

An input of 3:

```
1, 2
1, 4
1, 6
1, 8
1, 10
1, 12
1, 14
1, 16
1, 18
1, 20
1, 22
2, 1
2, 3
2, 4
2, 5
2, 7
2, 9
2, 10
2, 11
2, 13
2, 15
2, 16
2, 17
2, 19
2, 21
2, 22
2, 23
3, 2
3, 4
3, 6
3, 8
3, 10
3, 12
3, 14
3, 16
3, 18
3, 20
3, 22
4, 1
4, 2
4, 3
4, 5
4, 7
4, 8
4, 9
4, 11
4, 13
4, 14
4, 15
4, 17
4, 19
4, 20
4, 21
4, 23
5, 2
5, 4
5, 6
5, 8
5, 10
5, 12
5, 14
5, 16
5, 18
5, 20
5, 22
6, 1
6, 3
6, 5
6, 7
6, 9
6, 11
6, 13
6, 15
6, 17
6, 19
6, 21
6, 23
7, 2
7, 4
7, 6
7, 8
7, 10
7, 12
7, 14
7, 16
7, 18
7, 20
7, 22
8, 1
8, 3
8, 4
8, 5
8, 7
8, 9
8, 10
8, 11
8, 13
8, 15
8, 16
8, 17
8, 19
8, 21
8, 22
8, 23
9, 2
9, 4
9, 6
9, 8
9, 10
9, 12
9, 14
9, 16
9, 18
9, 20
9, 22
10, 1
10, 2
10, 3
10, 5
10, 7
10, 8
10, 9
10, 11
10, 13
10, 14
10, 15
10, 17
10, 19
10, 20
10, 21
10, 23
11, 2
11, 4
11, 6
11, 8
11, 10
11, 12
11, 14
11, 16
11, 18
11, 20
11, 22
12, 1
12, 3
12, 5
12, 7
12, 9
12, 11
12, 13
12, 15
12, 17
12, 19
12, 21
12, 23
13, 2
13, 4
13, 6
13, 8
13, 10
13, 12
13, 14
13, 16
13, 18
13, 20
13, 22
14, 1
14, 3
14, 4
14, 5
14, 7
14, 9
14, 10
14, 11
14, 13
14, 15
14, 16
14, 17
14, 19
14, 21
14, 22
14, 23
15, 2
15, 4
15, 6
15, 8
15, 10
15, 12
15, 14
15, 16
15, 18
15, 20
15, 22
16, 1
16, 2
16, 3
16, 5
16, 7
16, 8
16, 9
16, 11
16, 13
16, 14
16, 15
16, 17
16, 19
16, 20
16, 21
16, 23
17, 2
17, 4
17, 6
17, 8
17, 10
17, 12
17, 14
17, 16
17, 18
17, 20
17, 22
18, 1
18, 3
18, 5
18, 7
18, 9
18, 11
18, 13
18, 15
18, 17
18, 19
18, 21
18, 23
19, 2
19, 4
19, 6
19, 8
19, 10
19, 12
19, 14
19, 16
19, 18
19, 20
19, 22
20, 1
20, 3
20, 4
20, 5
20, 7
20, 9
20, 10
20, 11
20, 13
20, 15
20, 16
20, 17
20, 19
20, 21
20, 22
20, 23
21, 2
21, 4
21, 6
21, 8
21, 10
21, 12
21, 14
21, 16
21, 18
21, 20
21, 22
22, 1
22, 2
22, 3
22, 5
22, 7
22, 8
22, 9
22, 11
22, 13
22, 14
22, 15
22, 17
22, 19
22, 20
22, 21
22, 23
23, 2
23, 4
23, 6
23, 8
23, 10
23, 12
23, 14
23, 16
23, 18
23, 20
23, 22
```

An input of 5:

```
1, 4
1, 14
2, 2
2, 4
2, 6
2, 7
2, 8
2, 10
2, 12
2, 14
2, 16
2, 17
2, 18
2, 20
2, 22
3, 8
3, 18
4, 1
4, 2
4, 4
4, 6
4, 8
4, 10
4, 11
4, 12
4, 14
4, 16
4, 18
4, 20
4, 21
4, 22
6, 2
6, 4
6, 6
6, 8
6, 9
6, 10
6, 12
6, 14
6, 16
6, 18
6, 19
6, 20
6, 22
7, 2
7, 12
7, 22
8, 2
8, 3
8, 4
8, 6
8, 8
8, 10
8, 12
8, 13
8, 14
8, 16
8, 18
8, 20
8, 22
8, 23
9, 6
9, 16
10, 2
10, 4
10, 6
10, 8
10, 10
10, 12
10, 14
10, 16
10, 18
10, 20
10, 22
11, 4
11, 14
12, 2
12, 4
12, 6
12, 7
12, 8
12, 10
12, 12
12, 14
12, 16
12, 17
12, 18
12, 20
12, 22
13, 8
13, 18
14, 1
14, 2
14, 4
14, 6
14, 8
14, 10
14, 11
14, 12
14, 14
14, 16
14, 18
14, 20
14, 21
14, 22
16, 2
16, 4
16, 6
16, 8
16, 9
16, 10
16, 12
16, 14
16, 16
16, 18
16, 19
16, 20
16, 22
17, 2
17, 12
17, 22
18, 2
18, 3
18, 4
18, 6
18, 8
18, 10
18, 12
18, 13
18, 14
18, 16
18, 18
18, 20
18, 22
18, 23
19, 6
19, 16
20, 2
20, 4
20, 6
20, 8
20, 10
20, 12
20, 14
20, 16
20, 18
20, 20
20, 22
21, 4
21, 14
22, 2
22, 4
22, 6
22, 7
22, 8
22, 10
22, 12
22, 14
22, 16
22, 17
22, 18
22, 20
22, 22
23, 8
23, 18
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the lowest byte-count code without using standard loopholes is the winner.

As this is my first submission, any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a tad confused about *Given a 25 x 25 integer array*. Should our submissions *generate* this list or is it actually given on input?

Comment: Only the output matters. Generating the actual array is optional.

Comment: *"Imagine a battlefield of 625 foot soldiers"*  Right.  That's tall.  O_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>83 81 80</s>  76 bytes

The output is a space-delimited string of coordinates \$x,y\$.

```javascript
f=(n,x=y=23,k=5,v=x*y)=>y?(v&1|~v*k%n?[]:[x,y]+' ')+f(n,--x||23|!y--,k^6):[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvRCsIgFADQ976iHmreTQMnbTS47UPEYKwZ5dBoIQrSr1vP9Xrg3Ac/LOPz9ngx6y5TzhqJpQEj1oIaPFCPoYyAp9gTv@Pp7Uuztb1UnQw0qqpYF1Dpb2EspFSLtImMUXNuoJMqj84ubp72s7sSTYQAWP1Q@0f8yAHyBw)

#### How?

Let \$c_{x,y}=xy+1\$ be the value of the cell located at \$(x,y)\$.

Since the cells on the edge are not accounted, we assume \$0<x<24\$ and \$0<y<24\$.

\$c_{x,y}\$ is odd if either \$x\$ or \$y\$ is even (or both of them).

If \$x\$ is odd, then \$c_{x-1,y}\$ and \$c_{x+1,y}\$ are odd. But in that case, \$y\$ must be even, and so are \$c_{x,y-1}\$ and \$c_{x,y+1}\$. The sum of the cell and its odd surrounding neighbors is:

$$s_{x,y}=c_{x,y}+c_{x-1,y}+c_{x+1,y}=3c_{x,y}$$

Similarly, if \$y\$ is odd:

$$s_{x,y}=c_{x,y}+c_{x,y-1}+c_{x,y+1}=3c_{x,y}$$

If both \$x\$ and \$y\$ are even, all surrounding neighbors are odd:

$$s_{x,y}=c_{x,y}+c_{x-1,y}+c_{x+1,y}+c_{x,y-1}+c_{x,y+1}=5c_{x,y}$$

This multiplier (\$3\$ or \$5\$) is named \$k\$ in the JS code.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                 //   n      = input
  x = y = 23,        //   (x, y) = current coordinates, starting at (23, 23)
  k = 5,             //   k      = multiplier (3 or 5)
  v = x * y          //   v      = x * y (value of the current cell - 1)
) =>                 //
  y ?                // if y is greater than 0:
    ( v & 1 |        //   if v is odd (meaning that v + 1 is not)
      ~v * k % n ?   //   or n is not a divisor of -(v + 1) * k:
        []           //     append nothing
      :              //   else:
        [x, y] + ' ' //     append the coordinates followed by a space
    ) +              //
    f(               //   append the result of a recursive call:
      n,             //     pass n unchanged
      --x ||         //     decrement x; if the result is 0:
        23 | !y--,   //       pass 23 instead and decrement y
      k ^ 6          //     update k (5 -> 3 -> 5 -> ...)
    )                //   end of recursive call
  :                  // else:
    []               //   stop recursion
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful explanation. Clever using a bitwise XOR to flip between the multipliers.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>97</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s>  90 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=0,d=0,j;++i<24;d=5)for(j=0;++j<24;d^=6)if(i*j%2+(i*j+1)*d%x<1)Print((i,j));}
```

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCsIwFEX3fIVL4b2mQlOtIkkK7g5ubi5JAy9DCmmGgvjtMXHucDncc@Ga9WhWyneTaAmKQpqczpuePm6JUOqBdN/ZEi85JzWcpdUj1tHrvij/V299QXJArW8GXsEFtrbZlMBnLC8A1HlE@c2SORA3gZKxV6Q0PyjMUJuD03XX7smxIP8A)

Comment: `int i=0; ... int j=0;` can be `int i=0,j; ... j=0;` and `<1&` can be `+` for -4 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen For the int declarations, originally I had it that way until I changed my function to a different method, then reverted it. The `+` one is nice though, thanks

Comment: Another -2 by replacing `((i+j)%2>0?3:5)` with `(5-(i+j)%2*2)`

Comment: Suggest `i*j%2<=~(i*j)*d%x` instead of `i*j%2+(i*j+1)*d%x<1`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
lambda n:[(x,y)for x in R for y in R if~(x*y)*[5,3][x+y&1]%n<1>x*y%2]
R=range(1,24)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlqjQqdSMy2/SKFCITNPIUgBxKyEMDPT6jQqtCo1taJNdYxjoyu0K9UMY1XzbAztgKKqRrFcQbZFiXnpqRqGOkYmmv8LijLzShTSNIzNNbngbGME29DSEMbJSc3TAEpqovJNNTX/AwA)

Thanks to Arnauld for saving a byte.

Comment: Ah, basically the same program to my prepared js answer...

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âÖÅ{┼îÄï$εS╢,σδXú(Γ°#↑√nG
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83998f7bc58c8e8b24ee53b62ce5eb58a328e2f82318fb6e47&i=37%0A191%0A3%0A5&a=1&m=2)

This is mostly just brute force, with one marginally clever observation.  All odd troops have either 2 or 4 odd neighbors.  And the total sum of these plus the original solder is either `3p` or `5p` where `p` is the soldier's power.  The coefficient (3 or 5) can be determined by `gcd(2, x, y) * 2 + 1)` where `x` and `y` are the soldier's coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 69 bytes

```javascript
x=>{for(i=24;--i;)for(j=24,d=5;--j;d^=6)i*j%2+~(i*j)*d%x||print(j,i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjRCsIgFIDh@73H4LhmsK2CEHuUYEyNY8sjOmLR6tXtdPXz/X58jnlKGBeZIxqbHhTu9lWcLqu@vB0lQN0flJSoxF@e1Rp95OOVueqTwMbX/e4LXNGYet22mDAs4FsUn1I5GAahqolCptnuZ7oB00F37rjlBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
23×þ`‘µḤḤÐeÐe+×Ḃ³ḍaƊŒṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/I@PD0w/sSHjXMOLT14Y4lQHR4QioQaR@e/nBH06HND3f0Jh7rOjrp4c5V////NzYHAA)

A full program that takes a single argument, the secret power number, and implicitly prints a list of `[x, y]` pairs. Uses the observation others have made about multiples of 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
Position[If[2∣+##,5,3](1+1##)&~Array~{23,23},a_/;#∣a]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyC/OLMkMz8v2jMt2uhRx2JtZWUdUx3jWA1DbUNlZU21OseiosTKumojYx0j41qdxHh9a2WgssRYtf8BRZl5JdHKunZpDso6SjF5SrFq@g7VXMbmOlyGloY6XMY6XKZctf8B)

Looked around after posting and realized I really needed to turn my brain on...